# find and replace with sed

Tags: bash, replace, sed, find

I have the following problem.

I have a file with a lot of words inside what I have to do is find these words in another file and replace them with just one letter.

I do not know the words that I have to delete (too many!) so I don't know how to use the following sed command

```
$ sed -i 's/words_old/word_new/g' /home/user/test.txt
```

however I think I have to use also the cat command:

```
$ cat filewithwordstobedeleted.txt
```

but I don't know how to combine them.

Thank you for helping me! :)

Fabio

Comment: Where do the word_new come from? Are they also specified in filewithwordstobedeleted.txt, next to each word, or do you replace all words with the same letter?

Comment: I have to replace all the words with just the word "null"

Comment: Beware of making a [clbuttic](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx) mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A simple shell loop could help you here, assuming you have one word-to-be-deleted per line:

```
cat filewithwordstobedeleted.txt | while read word; do
    sed -i "s/$word/null/g" /home/user/test.txt
done
```

Note that the use of `cat` is not strictly necessary, but makes this example easier to read.

Comment: For the curious, a cat-less alternative is `while read word; do ...; done < filewithwordstobedeleted.txt`

Comment: This was also going to be my suggestion. I was wondering, however, if it would be slower, due to the multiple invocations of sed, than if you could somehow do it with a single sed run?

Comment: I've tried but it works in a strange way maybe is due to the fact that I do not have one word per line. So instead of replacing each word with "null" is putting "null" in each line. It should work in this way: orange pineapple apple (same line) --> null null null or orangepineappleapple --> nullnullnull

Answer (score 0):

If your list of words is one-per-line and not ridiculously long:

```
sed -ri "s/$(tr "\n" "|" < filewithwordstobedeleted.txt | head -c-1)/null/g" /home/user/test.txt
```

Comment: no, unfortunately is not a list of words but a series of words on the same line like: orange pineapple apple (same line) that I would like to have as null null null or orangepineappleapple --> nullnullnull. Yes, it is ridiculously long but the time is not a problem. I can leave it running on a server w/o any issue.

Comment: @fabioln79: I mean if the list of words to be deleted (filewithwordstobedeleted.txt) is one per line. My command works if the file to modify has multiple words per line. The length isn't about the runtime, but whether it exceeds the command line capacity of the system you're running on (2MB on my system).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
# cat <<\! >/tmp/a
> this
> that
> those
> !
cat <<\! >/tmp/b
> a
> those
> b
> this
> c
> that
> d
> !
sed 's|.*|s/&/null/g|' /tmp/a
s/this/null/g
s/that/null/g
s/those/null/g
sed 's|.*|s/&/null/g|' /tmp/a | sed -f - /tmp/b
a
null
b
null
c
null
d
cat <<\! >/tmp/c
> a
> this and that and those
> b
> this and that
> c
> those
> !
sed 's|.*|s/&/null/g|' /tmp/a | sed -f - /tmp/c
a
null and null and null
b
null and null
c
null
```